# How to add a line break into a mailto link that is being encoded with PHP's rawurlencode

Tags: php, html

I have something like this.

```
<a href='mailto:mike@example.com?subject=<?php print rawurlencode('This is the subject.');?>&body=<?php print rawurlencode('Line 1 of body. Line 2 of body.');?>'>Email</a>
```

I want to put a line break in the body of the message. I found via google that you can put %0D%0A into the mailto to do a line break but the problem is that rawurlencode will just encode it. What could I put into rawurlencode in order to get the line break to show up in the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\r\n` characters in your string if you use double quotes, this will avoid the double encoding issue you're describing.

```
<?php
echo rawurlencode("Line One.\r\nLine Two.");
/* Line%20One.%0D%0ALine%20Two. */
```

The [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function might be handy too.

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'subject'   => 'Subject',
    'body'      => "Line One.\r\nLine Two."
);

echo http_build_query($params);
/* subject=Subject&body=Line+One.%0D%0ALine+Two. */
```

Comment: No combinations of \r and/or \n seems to work. They just come through in the message body as \r and \n

Answer (score 0):

`\n` - this is called linefeed - special character

Comment: @cody-gray, It was me, who tried to point that `\r\n` is Windows-specific. Tried again, hopefully successfull this time :)